# Storage Space/HD space on iPhone via code

Tags: iphone, memory, storage, hard-drive

How do I get the amount of storage room left on the iPhone? I need to be able to ge the info that you can get with appbox pro, ie. space used, space available, space total, all in GB.

How can I access it in-app without the use of private APIs? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the zip file (not the source) at http://kdbdallas.com/2008/12/27/maciphone-show-availble-useable-diskspace/ - I'm using it in my projects and it works.

I made some changes (I needed bytes) but you have the code below for all units:

```
-(int) bytesAvailable {
    float availableDisk = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
    int bytes = availableDisk;
    return (int)bytes;
}

-(int) kilosAvailable {
    float availableDisk = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
    int kilos = availableDisk/1024;
    return (int)kilos;
}

-(int) megasAvailable {
    float availableDisk = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
    int megas = availableDisk/1024/1024;
    return (int)megas;
}

-(int) gigasAvailable {
    float availableDisk = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
    int gigas = availableDisk/1024/1024/1024;
    return (int)gigas;
}
```

And to use it you just call:

```
FSStats *stats = [[FSStats alloc] initWithFilePath:@"/"];
int freeSpace = [stats bytesAvailable];
```

To get the total size you just use the "f_bsize":

```
float availableDisk = (float)(tStats.f_bavail * tStats.f_bsize);
float totalSize = (float)(tStats.f_bsize * tStats.f_bsize);
NSLog(@"Total size: %.2f | Free: %.2f", totalSize, availableDisk);
```

all credit goes to Dallas Brown http://kdbdallas.com/

Comment: +1 for the ref to Dallas Brown but you changed one too many things; provide the app's document directory to FSStats, not @"/".  I get 5.9GB from the document directory (same as reported by iTunes) but only 139MB from @"/".  Some kind of file permissions issue I guess.